# i want to print a series using recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion, series

You have to print a pattern using recursion. Given a input 
N
 the pattern looks like this
N
, 
a
i
, 
a
i
+
1
, 
a
i
+
2
,.....,
N
. Where if 
a
i
>
0
 then 
a
i
+
1
 = 
a
i
−
5
 else 
a
i
+
1
 = 
a
i
+
5
. It will be a decreasing sequence from 
N
 till 
a
i
<=
0
 and then an increasing sequence till 
N
. (See sample test cases for better explanation)

Input format
First line contains an integer 
T
 denoting number of test cases.
For each of the next 
T
 lines, each line contains an integer 
N
.

Output format
For each test case on a new line, print the required pattern.

Constraints
1
<=
T
<=
6

0
<=
N
<=
2000

Example
Input

2

16

10

Output

16 11 6 1 -4 1 6 11 16

10 5 0 5 10

Sample test case explanation
For the first test case
N=16, it will be a decreasing sequence till the printing number becomes <=0.
16 11 6 1 −4
After this point it will be a increasing sequence till the printing number becomes N
1 6 11 16
So the pattern is 16 11 6 1 −4 1 6 11 16.

My code is below but i got the output as 16,11,6,1,-4 only. Help me to correct this code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Day3
{  
public static void series(int n,boolean b)
{
    int temp = n;
    boolean flag=b;
    System.out.println(temp+" ");
    if(flag==true)
        temp-=5;
    else if(flag==false)
        temp+=5;
    if(temp<=0)
        flag=false;
    if(temp<=n)
        series(temp,flag);
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    while(t>0)
    {
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        series(n,true);
        t-=1;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Well first thing is you aren't even using recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Because 'n' changes in every cases. You must create another variable and keep first 'n' in that, for control if temp smaller than 'n'.

For example

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Day3
{  

int firstN = 0; //added that line

public static void series(int n,boolean b)
{
    int temp = n;
    boolean flag=b;
    System.out.println(temp+" ");
    if(flag==true)
        temp-=5;
    else if(flag==false)
        temp+=5;
    if(temp<=0)
        flag=false;
    if(temp<=firstN) //changed that line
        series(temp,flag);
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    while(t>0)
    {
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        firstN = n; //added that line
        series(n,true);
        t-=1;
    }
}
}
```

Also a little tip;

you can use `(flag)` for `(flag==true)`

and `(!flag)` for `(flag==false)`

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI : Although this can be solved using recursion, it can be solved more efficiently without using recursion. It is as simple as this:

```
private static void printSeries(int N) {
      int T = N;
      while ( T >= 0 ) {
        System.out.print(T +  " ");
        T = T - 5;
      }
      while ( T <= N ) {
         System.out.print(T +  " ");
        T = T + 5;
      }
    }
```